# Github Actions environments and their variables

Tags: github-actions

I have environments configured in Github for my workflow (`dev` and `prod`). My question is: can I somehow reference variables defined in those environments in a step executed outside of environment? Something like `${{ vars.dev.YY }}`?

I can't run those steps within the environment as I have a rule asking for a review/approval of flows in those environments. To be more specific: I want `terraform plan` to be executed w/o an approval, but `terraform apply` to require review. And I wanted to use variables configured for each of the environments to configure terraform execution.

Thank you

Comment: You can't :/ What you can do is duplicate the `vars` you need at the repository level, to access them from workflows not using the specific environment.

Comment: Sigh, thank you @GuiFalourd, that's what I thought :(